# “This operation requires the merged cells to be identically sized.” when copying a range VBA

Tags: vba, merge

I have code that copies a range from a sheet in one workbook and pastes it in a sheet in another workbook. The range includes merged cells (I didn't design it). The range it pastes the data is formatted exactly the same as where it is copied from. I tested the VBA by copying it to blank workbooks, and it works. However, when I try to copy it to a the worksheet that already has that same formatting, it gives the “This operation requires the merged cells to be identically sized.” error, and I'm unsure how to get around this. Here is what I have:

```
Sub testcopying()
Dim FileNm As Object, Cnt As Integer
Dim TargetFiles As FileDialog
 Set TargetFiles = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
 With TargetFiles
 .AllowMultiSelect = True
 .Title = "Multi-select target data files:"
 .ButtonName = ""
 .Filters.Clear
 .Filters.Add "*.xls* files", "*.xls*"
 .Show
 End With
If TargetFiles.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
 MsgBox "PICK A FILE!"
 Exit Sub
 End If
'On Error GoTo below
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Cnt = 1 To TargetFiles.SelectedItems.Count
 'open the file and assign the workbook/worksheet
Set FileNm = Workbooks.Open(TargetFiles.SelectedItems(Cnt))

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vendor Data Sheets").Range("A1:AJ191").Copy

Workbooks(FileNm.Name).Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Workbooks(FileNm.Name).Close SaveChanges:=True
Next Cnt
below:
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "File Error"
End Sub
```

Any thoughts? I think I may have to write it so it unmerges every cell before pasting the data, then re-merges it, as it was able to successfully paste in the blank workbook (with no merging). But with hundreds of different merged cells, that would take a bit to type up, so I'm hoping there are easier answers. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting around "This operation requires the merged cells to be identically sized."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48913954/getting-around-this-operation-requires-the-merged-cells-to-be-identically-sized)

Comment: Did you try the comments from your last question? `Workbooks(FileNm.Name).Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats` before pasting the values?

Comment: @braX I made the new question as someone suggested to post all the code and it wouldn't fit in the comment box. &Scott Craner I did try adding that line but am still getting the same error.

Comment: @UncleBajubjubs one would usually use the [edit] function and add the code instead of creating a new question.

Comment: @ScottCraner, My apologies, I'm new to this forum, should I delete this one and update the old one then?

Comment: At this point I would delete the prior as this is better.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here `xlPasteValues`- you cannot paste only values because you are copying also formats (merged cells)

If it's not essential for you to keep the formatting ( as you said those are the same in all workbooks) you can just remove `xlPasteValues` from your code.

Comment: That solution does allow it to run without error, thank you. Is there another way to make the code do what xlPasteValues does? I'd like to make it just copy the values, and not the formulas.

Comment: @UncleBajubjubs the workaround solution would be to copy the sheet and paste it again as values. So your code would look like this:  `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vendor Data Sheets").Range("A1:AJ191").Copy
Workbooks(FileNm.Name).Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Workbooks(FileNm.Name).Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy
Workbooks(FileNm.Name).Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False`

Answer (score 0):

Reason #1 of many: It is very possible you accidentally have selected two worksheets before making the change as I have done in my case.